# Writing Apps for 4.0 and 2.3

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to write an app that will serve a nice interface to users using 4.0 and 2.2.. I would like to add an action bar for 4.0+, but use a different form of navigation for 2.2-2.3. What is the recommended way to do this?

Comment: Particularly with 2.x steadily declining in market share, I'd go with an action bar for all versions, using ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: Would it be best to write two versions?

Comment: ActionBarSherlock lets you use the same code to have an action bar from Android 2.1 onwards.

Comment: @CommonsWare if you post your answer of actionbar sherlock I will put it as the answer. That's what I ended up using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The action bar pattern was in use on a reasonable number of Android apps -- notably Twitter -- back in the Android 2.x days. Hence, Android 2.x users are likely to recognize what it is and what you do with it.

Given that, plus the steady decline in Android 2.x market share, I'd go with an action bar pattern across the board, probably using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) as a backport of the action bar to Android 2.x. In ~18 months or so, if you drop Android 2.x support entirely, it will be a fairly small change to switch to the native action bar.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way is to use a different layout file for 2.2-2.3.   Essentially create a layout-v11 in your res folder. Whenever your app loads a layout if it is Honeycomb or later it will check that folder first.  You can use other versions as well, depending on the sdk version you will target.

You will probably also want to have a values-v11 where you put a style that derives from Holo and a different style in the values folder.  Your app will load the appropriate style depending on which version it is running on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same senario and used the Google IO 2012 code for some great examples, you can find the source code in the following git repo.

```
git clone https://code.google.com/p/iosched/
```

The project utilizes action bar sherlock and the support libraries. It is also built to support most devices, phone, tablet and even google TV.

Comment: Yes, ActionBarSherlock is the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

The smartest and most reliable way to do this task it by using the latest API (17) which will automatically use what ever is native for android 4.2.2 and lower. Please consider "1 upping" me if I gave you some sort of idea to help you!

Hope this helps.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question of how to write an app for Android 2.3?